# Cannot play DAV to MP4 converted H.265 video file with hvc1 tag in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, mp4, hevc

I have converted H.265 video file in dav format from Dahua camera using following commands. Both of the generated mp4 video files are NOT playable in iPhone default player. However, the generated video files are playable in VLC player.

```
ffmpeg -y -i hevc.dav -c:v copy -tag:v hvc1 hevc.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i hevc.dav -tag:v hvc1 -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov hevc.mp4
```

Generated video file plays only if I re-encode the video using following command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i hevc.dav -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 hevc.mp4
```

Re-encoding is time consuming. So, please let me know, if I am missing any flags in the above commands.

Comment: Have you double-checked that your source file really contains h.265 encoded video? How did you check?

Comment: What happens if you convert without setting -tag?

Comment: What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: @soundflix, I have checked that the the source file contains the h.265 encoded video using ffprobe command. Here is the output: Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 2560x1440, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc. Also, I have tried without -tag and it did not play. Video perfectly plays in VLC player.

Comment: @VenkataSubbarao There might be other factors affecting playback like **colorspace** settings, etc. Can you provide two testable files (one from "codec copy" method, and the one from "re-encoding" method)? The files can be 1 second short. The solution is likely coming from checking numbers in the file bytes (for differences that might affect playback).

Comment: @VenkataSubbarao PS: Does Safari accept the H.265 video if you "codec copy" into MOV instead of into MP4? Try as: `ffmpeg -y -i hevc.dav -c:v copy -an hevc.mov` ... Sorry but there's no Safari here (Windows) to give you a pre-tested answer. PPS: If you can provide us with a working file versus a not-working file then we can simply advise what other FFmpeg options are required/missing without ever needing Safari.

Comment: @VC.One, I had tried this and did not work. I have investigated this further and posted the answer.

Comment: Okay, I see from your Answer that you had miscellaneous bytes before the real DAV begins. Otherwise using Apple's own MOV container is recommended for Safari usage when other formats fail to work. MOV accepts many types of audio/video codecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: 
Input File had some extra bytes at the beginning (the first 46kb) and which came before the actual DAV header. **Removing these exra bytes** made for a new output DAV file that FFmpeg would then accept and correctly mux into MP4.

Future readers can look into these research points:

- [Dahua NVR - DAV file format analysis](https://www.sl.id.au/posts/dahua-pvr-files/)
- [FFmpeg DHAV parser source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/dhav.c#L56)

**Process:**
I verified the source **.dav** file using `hexdump -C` command and found that the at the start of the file the bytes are not DHAV. It gave me a clue that the first HEVC frame is not complete.

I wrote a small C program to search whether there are further DHAV bytes in the file and I found the DHAV after about 46KB. I removed these partial bytes from the beginning of the file and wrote the remaining bytes to another file named **hevc_cropped_bytes.dav** and ran the following command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i hevc_cropped_bytes.dav -c:v copy -tag:v hvc1 hevc.mp4
```

This time the generated video file is properly played. Here is the program that removes the partial bytes from the beginning of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096

int main()
{
    FILE *inputFile, *outputFile;
    char signature[] = "DHAV";
    unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    unsigned char *ptr;
    int bytesRead;
    int found = 0;

    // Open the input binary file
    inputFile = fopen("hevc.dav", "rb");
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening input file");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the output binary file
    outputFile = fopen("hevc_cropped.dav", "wb");
    if (outputFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error creating output file");
        fclose(inputFile);
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the initial chunk
    bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BUF_SIZE, inputFile);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        ptr = buffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead - 3; i++, ptr++) {
            if (memcmp(ptr, signature, 4) == 0) {
                if (ptr < buffer + bytesRead) {
                    // Found the complete signature
                    // Write the remaining bytes after the signature to the output file
                    fwrite(ptr, sizeof(unsigned char), buffer + bytesRead - ptr, outputFile);
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (found == 0) {
            // Shift the last 3 bytes to the beginning of the buffer
            memmove(buffer, ptr, 3);

            // Read the next chunk
            bytesRead = fread(buffer + 3, sizeof(char), BUF_SIZE - (sizeof(signature) - 1), inputFile);
            bytesRead += 3; // Remaining from previous chunk
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (!feof(inputFile)) {
        bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BUF_SIZE, inputFile);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), bytesRead, outputFile);
    }

    // Close files
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Only thing left is to recommend downloading an actual hex editor (is better than just getting a hex dump in the terminal). PS: Maybe also add the code of your small C program to strengthen your posted Answer. I assume it seeks ahead to the actual start position of the DAV's header bytes?

Comment: @VC.One, yes, it seeks ahead before writing to another file. Added the code that removes the partial bytes from the beginning of the file.